# Which table is left table in left join on multi-join?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, join, left-join

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t1.t2_id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t2.t3_id
LEFT JOIN t4 ON t4.id = t1.t4_id
```

Which is a left table when left joining t4? Is it previous result set - combination od previous joins, or a table before, which is t3, or is it t1 because of ON clause?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. A `LEFT JOIN` means that you retain rows from the prior results, regardless of if a related row is found in the joined table or not. They are *both* `LEFT JOIN`ed, so both behave that way.

Comment: In this case it is a virtual table of all previous joins.  `(t1 JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t1.t2_id LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t2.t3_id) LEFT JOIN t4 ON t4.id = t1.t4_id` The position of the ON clauses controls this https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125423/3690

Comment: @ThomA I know what left join does. I have multiple joins and want to know with which result set I am joining my t4, so I know what to expect, for debugging purposes

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135436/multiple-left-joins-what-is-the-left-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can consider the `LEFT` table in the join against `t4` to be

```
SELECT *
FROM   t1
       INNER JOIN t2
               ON t2.id = t1.t2_id
       LEFT JOIN t3
              ON t3.id = t2.t3_id
```

This is the typical case where every `JOIN` clause has an `ON` clause immediately afterwards.

It is possible to not do that though.

As an example for the query

```
SELECT *
FROM   t1
       LEFT JOIN t2
              ON t2.id = t1.t2_id
       INNER JOIN t3
                  LEFT JOIN t4
                         ON t4.id = t3.t4_id
               ON t3.id = t1.t3_id
```

Then **logically**

- `t1` is left joined to `t2` - call that `t1_t2`
- `t3` is left joined to `t4` - call that `t3_t4`
- `t1_t2` is inner joined to `t3_t4`

The placement of the `ON` clause controls this